# How to update styles on child component onPress in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created a component for react native to display a option list (radiobutton).

It basically is a TouchableOpacity with a View and Text. A view to display the radiobutton circle and a text for the label. I've added an onPress handler to the TouchableOpactiy. I want to change the style on the View inside the TouchabelOpacity...

I thought that on state change the component would update...

What am I missing/doing wrong?

This is part of my code (full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/7knoyx5v9j)

```
class RadioButton extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.selected ? props.selected : null };
    this.handleRadioButtonChange = this.handleRadioButtonChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleRadioButtonChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { disabled, name, options } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    const radioOptions = options.map(radio => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={radio[1].toString()}
        id={value}
        name={name}
        value={radio[1]}
        disabled={disabled}
        onPress={this.handleRadioButtonChange}
      >
        <View style={value === radio[1] ? styleActive : styleInactive} />
        <Text>{radio[0]}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
    return radioOptions;
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of passing an array of options to the radio button class and then mapping them in the class, try to make the radio button a component singular and map over the options array to create the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya your value is undefined..
use this modified code, Now it is working as you want..

```
    class RadioButton extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.selected ? props.selected : null };
  }
  handleRadioButtonChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event });
  };
  render() {
    const { disabled, name, options } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    const radioOptions = options.map(radio => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={radio[1].toString()}
        id={value}
        name={name}
        value={radio[1]}
        disabled={disabled}
        onPress={() => this.handleRadioButtonChange(radio[1])}
      >
        <View style={value === radio[1] ? styleActive : styleInactive} />
        <Text>{radio[0]}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
    return radioOptions;
  }
}
```

Go in detail of why i m using arrow instead of bind..
try this code with both, it will give you the more interesting facts

Answer (score 0):

The `event.target.value` is `undefined` , therefore the condition always renders inactive styles.

```
handleRadioButtonChange = value => event => {
    this.setState({ value });
};

<TouchableOpacity
   ...
   onPress={this.handleRadioButtonChange(radio[1])}
>
```

Checkout more about the events [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system)